# Call actionPerformed with different parameters in Java

Tags: java, swing

Since I'm new to Java graphics (and Java in general), I decided to try and work on some examples. One of them was solar system and while I managed to make it, I have one problem with it - I don't know how to set the speed of planets so it would be different for every one of them. I tried different ideas and read a lot online but for now I'm stuck. This is the code:

```
public class solarsystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System wnd = new System();
        wnd.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        wnd.setSize(1000,1000);
        wnd.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Planets extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    int r = 70;
    int r2 = 5;
    int r3 = 10;
    int center_x, center_y;
    double angle;
    Timer timer;
    Planets(){
        super();
        timer = new Timer(100, this);
        timer.start();
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        angle+=0.05;
        if(angle > (2*Math.PI))
            angle = 0.0;
        repaint();
    }
    public void DrawSun(int a, int b, int r, Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(a, b, r, r);
    }
    public void DrawPlanet(int a, int b, int r, Graphics g) {
        g.fillOval(a, b, r, r);
    }
    public int moveXParam(double number) {
        int move_x = (int) (Math.cos(angle) * (getWidth()/number) + (getWidth()/2));
        return move_x;
    }
    public int moveYParam(double number) {
        int move_y = (int) (Math.sin(angle) * (getHeight()/ number) + (getHeight()/ 2));
        return move_y;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        center_x = getWidth()/2;
        center_y = getHeight()/2;
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        //drawin Sun
        g2d.setColor(new Color(255,255,0));
        DrawSun(center_x-(r/2), center_y-(r/2), r, g);
        //Mercury
        g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        DrawPlanet(moveXParam(9), moveYParam(9), r2, g);
        //Venus
        g2d.setColor(new Color(153, 76, 0));
        DrawPlanet(moveXParam(8), moveYParam(8), r3, g);
    }
}
class System extends JFrame{
    public System() {
        setContentPane(new Planets());
        setTitle("Solar System");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the part of the code managing the speed is `angle+=0.05;` in `actionPerformed` method and no matter how I tried to go around it (using switch cases, different methods etc. to input different angle change for every planet) I keep ending in the same place which is having to pass arguments to actionPerformed, and I can't do that. From what I gathered, no matter what I change, the final angle change will be the one that will be applied, because of `repaint()`. Now, this is the first time I'm ever using `ActionListener` and anything similar, so I decided to ask for help.

So, is there any way to change `angle+=0.05` so that for example it stays like that for Mercury, but for Venus it's `angle+=0.07`? Or should I completely ditch `actionPerformed` and just try to implement different methods for this? Thank you. (Also, as I said, I'm new to this, so if I made any mistakes in the title/obvious mistakes in the code/didn't explain what I mean clearly, please let me know).

Comment: Pass some type of delta value to `moveXParam` and `moveYParam` that is going to be different for each planet and that can be added to the `angle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are new to object oriented programming. You have a number of different speeds, angles, colours and what not, yet you try to handle them all with a single variable. What I did in my solution is to create a new `StellarObject` class, which holds all this variables. It also has an `update()` method and a `draw()` method which you can call to update all physics related variables and draw the object to the canvas respectively. They are all stored in a `List` (you could as well use an array if you know the number of objects wont change) and iterate over them to call their methods.

Also, while it is not wrong to make `Planets` implement `ActionListener`, it certainly is an uncommon way of doing it. When you are writing object oriented code, try to think if `Planets` really is listening for an action. You could argue that a tick in physics is an action, but then so could be the draw event and other things. Usually you would create separate `ActionListener`s for each action you want to be notified of. We are using lambda notation to make everything a little more compact with `new Timer(100, e -> update());`. That internally creates a new `ActionListener` which simply calls the `update()` method. We also use lambda notation when we call `stellarObjects.forEach(StellarObject::update);`, which will iterate over all `StellarObject`s and call their `update()` method.

```
public class Planets extends JPanel {
    private List<StellarObject> stellarObjects = new LinkedList<>();
    private Timer timer;
    private StellarObject sun = new StellarObject(0, 0, new Color(255, 255, 0), 70);
    private StellarObject mercury = new StellarObject(9, 0.07, new Color(255, 0, 0), 5);
    private StellarObject venus = new StellarObject(8, 0.05, new Color(153, 76, 0), 10);

    public Planets(){
        super();
        timer = new Timer(100, e -> update());
        timer.start();
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        Collections.addAll(stellarObjects, sun, mercury, venus);
    }

    public void update() {
        stellarObjects.forEach(StellarObject::update);
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (StellarObject stellarObject : stellarObjects) {
            stellarObject.draw(g);
        }
    }

    public class StellarObject {
        private int distance;
        private double angle;
        private double angularVelocity;
        private Color color;
        private int radius;

        public StellarObject(int distance, double angularVelocity, Color color, int radius) {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.angularVelocity = angularVelocity;
            this.color = color;
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(xDelta() - radius / 2, yDelta() - radius / 2, radius, radius);
        }

        private void update() {
            angle += angularVelocity;
            angle %= 2 * Math.PI;
        }

        public int xDelta() {
            return (int) ((distance == 0 ? 0 : Math.cos(angle) * (getWidth() / distance)) + (getWidth() / 2));
        }

        public int yDelta() {
            return (int) ((distance == 0 ? 0 : Math.sin(angle) * (getHeight() / distance)) + (getHeight() / 2));
        }
    }
}
```

If you are looking to improve your java skill further you may want to get familiar with the java specific conventions: always make fields `private` and only let them be accessible via getter and setter. All method names should be **c**amelCase (call it `drawPlanet`, not `DrawPlanet`). Class names should always be **C**amelCase (call it `SolarSystem`, not `solarsystem`).

Comment: thanks for this thorough explanation! I'm gonna look through it and try to improve my code. I have only one remark though - when I tried running your code, I get errors on `private List<StellarObject> stellarObjects = new LinkedList<>();` and all the following uses of `stellarObjects`. The error is `type List is not generic`. Is that because I'm not including a specific library?

Comment: the problem is probably that you are using `import java.awt.*;`. the `awt` package contains a non-generic class called `List` as well, so the compiler is confused. You just need to add `import java.util.List;` to your imports, but add it **behind** `import java.awt.*;`

Comment: alternatively you can change `private List<StellarObject> stellarObjects = new LinkedList<>();` to `private java.util.List<StellarObject> stellarObjects = new LinkedList<>();`

Comment: Tried both options, and while they cancelled some of the errors, I still get two - `LinkedList cannot be resolved to a type` and same for `Collections`. Sorry for the uh, additional questions, but I can't figure out why it won't work?

Comment: this is because you didn't import any of the classes. you see the list of `import` statements at the top of your files? these are there to tell the compiler which classes you are referring to when you use a specific name. which IDE are you using? most IDEs have an auto-import feature, where you can just select an unknown type and it will try to determine for you which `import` statements are missing.

Comment: for your particular case you can just add these 3: 
`import java.util.Collections;`
`import java.util.LinkedList;`
`import java.util.List;`

Comment: also be so kind and consider upvoting this answer if you get it to work :)